# Is it possible to do anisotropic IDW estimation (and cross validation) using gstat in R?

Tags: gstat

I am comparing cross validation ("leave one out") results for different variogram models for a 3D data set using the gstat library in R. I would like to compare similar cross validation results for inverse distance estimates as well, but I can't see how to do anisotropic estimations (or cross validation) with IDW in gstat. Is IDW in gstat estimation limited to isotropic estimation, and if not, what syntax can be applied?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is not possible to do anisotropic IDW estimations in gstat, I translated the data locations to make them isotropic, then conducted cross-validation using krige.cv.

Starting with a csv file with X,Y,Z,HM values (X, Y and Z translated to make the points isotropic - in this case XY rotated by 15 degrees, then X coordinates multiplied by 3.333 and Z values multiplied by 30: "hm_assays_iso.csv"). The R session I used was as follows:

> library(gstat)

> library(sp)

> hm_iso<-read.csv("hm_assays_iso.csv")

> coordinates(hm_iso)<- c("X", "Y", "Z")

> hm_idw.cv<-krige.cv(HM~1, locations=hm_iso, set=list(idp = 3))

> write.csv(hm_idw.cv, file="hm_cv_idw3.csv")